# Apache Solr : Error : unknown field _src_

Tags: solr, solrj, solrconfig

I went through [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html#setting-json-defaults) link and added the code in one of core to upload a multilevel JSON and it worked very well but when I created another core and added same  then it is throwing the below error. I spent so much time to solve this error but no luck.
The error is,

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":93},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"ERROR: [doc=5b62d25] unknown field '_src_'",
    "code":400}}
```

I have added the below code in my solrconfig.xml file.

```
<initParams path="/update/json/docs">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <!-- this ensures that the entire JSON doc will be stored verbatim into one field -->
    <str name="srcField">_src_</str>
    <!-- This means a the uniqueKeyField will be extracted from the fields and
         all fields go into the 'df' field. In this config df is already configured to be 'text'
     -->
    <str name="mapUniqueKeyOnly">true</str>
    <!-- The default search field where all the values are indexed to -->
    <str name="df">text</str>
  </lst>
</initParams>
```

It means my entire JSON will be stored against the key *src*.

Comment: you must add in your schema.xml a field name `_src_`

Comment: @Quent: No, its not working :(

Comment: @ShubhangiShinde: Did you restart the server after the update?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti :  yes, I restart.

Comment: Does the field show up in the schema browser i Solr's admin panel? Does it show up under the analysis tab? If not, it's not defined correctly.

Comment: I have added the code in my solrconfig.xml file. I have just edited my question and mentioned the code.

Comment: And how did you define it in schema.xml?

Comment: The `solrconfig.xml` file does not define available fields. Either you'll have to use the schemaless mode (where fields are created automagically for you - fine for prototyping, but nothing more), or you have to define the fields yourself. Your error message tells you that schemaless mode is not active, and your field is not defined (so it hasn't been added to `schema.xml`).

Comment: @Quent : They have mentioned that 'The _src_ field ensures that the entire JSON doc will be stored verbatim into one field', so I didn't understand whether we have to define _src_ anywhere in schema.xml file. Because they didn't mention about defining the _src_.

Comment: @MatsLindh :   I have difined the _src field like this in schema.xml,
<field name="_src_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

Comment: Maybe a typo, but should the field should be "_ src _" and not "_src" (missing underscore)?

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that you are using the params.json file provided by the *default* configuration, even though you are using your own schema.xml file. Have a look at the core's conf folder and look for the params.json file. If you find it over there, comment it all out.